# R - create new variable using if statement

Tags: string, r, variables, if-statement

I am trying to create a new variable within data table under `if` statement: if string variable contains substring, then new variable equals to numerical value.

My data:

```
N X
1 aa1aa 
2 bb2bb
3 cc-1bb 
...
```

Dataframe contains several thousands of rows.

Result needed is new column containing numerical value which is withing string (X collumn):

```
N X      Y
1 aa1aa  1
2 bb2bb  2
3 cc-1bb -1
```

I was trying with

```
for (i in 1:length(mydata)){
  if (grep('1', mydata$X) == TRUE) {
    mydata$Y <- 1  }
```

but I'm not sure if I'm even on correct way... Any help please?

Comment: `mydata$Y <- as.integer( grepl( "1" , mydata$X ) )`. However if it doesn't include the string `"1"` what should the value for `mydata$Y` take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work on more of your extended samples. Basically it takes out everything that's not a letter from the middle of the string.

```
X <- c("aa1aa", "bb2bb", "cc-1bb","aa+0.5b","fg-0.25h")
gsub("^[a-z]+([^a-z]*)[a-z]+$","\\1",X,perl=T)
#[1] "1"     "2"     "-1"    "+0.5"  "-0.25"
```

Comment: This works great with example dataset. But when i run this with original dataset result is just the same value from X collumn :( any ideas? for example X value is "Greuther Furth [-0.25]" i need -0.25 as a result but i get the same "Greuther Furth [-0.25]".. Is it because im working with dataframe with 16 collumns? Im new to R.. this was so easy with SAS :/

Comment: Basecaly variable X is string containing numbers -0.5, -0.25, 0, +0.25, +0.5. Most complicated variable would be for example "Xyz 07 [+0.25]" i need to get numerical 0.25 into my new value Y.

Comment: Well, regular expressions are very specific so when creating one you really need to know what the data looks like exactly. If those are the only values you are trying to find, how about gsub(".*?(-0.5|-0.25|0|\\+0.25|\\+0.5).*","\\1",X,perl=T)

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
d <- data.frame(N = 1:3,
                X = c('aa1aa', 'bb2bb', 'cc-1bb'),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(stringr)

d$Y <- as.numeric(str_extract_all(d$X,"\\(?[0-9,.]+\\)?"))

d

  N      X  Y
1 1  aa1aa  1
2 2  bb2bb  2
3 3 cc-1bb  1
```

EDIT - Speed test

The gsub approch provided by **@Simon** is much faster than stringr

```
library(microbenchmark)
# 30000 lines data.frame
d1 <- data.frame(N = 1:30000,
                X = rep(c('aa1aa', 'bb2bb', 'cc-1bb'), 10000),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

stringr

```
microbenchmark(as.numeric(str_extract_all(d1$X,"\\(?[0-9,.]+\\)?")), 
               times = 10L)
Unit: seconds
                                                      expr      min      lq  median       uq      max neval
 as.numeric(str_extract_all(d1$X, "\\\\(?[0-9,.]+\\\\)?")) 2.677408 2.75283 2.76473 2.781083 2.796648    10
```

base gsub

```
microbenchmark(gsub( "[^0-9]" , "" , d1$X ), times = 10L)
Unit: milliseconds
                     expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 gsub("[^0-9]", "", d1$X) 44.95564 45.05358 45.07238 45.10201 45.23645    10
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the example data from **@Paulo** you can use `gsub` from `base` R...

```
d$Y <- gsub( "[^0-9]" , "" , d$X )
```

Comment: thank you very much!
Maby you know how to make this work if i need to extract numerical value from string which is for example aa+0.5b or fg-0.25h ?